# Unknown file in AEM, un-cached. How to remove or find its origin

Tags: javascript, seo, aem

Hello I have a file which I can't find the origin for. In AEM, how can I find the origin of this file, and where can I remove it or cache for a week.

The file URL is as follows:

https://www.companyName.com/webcontent/a1f7176bui17230aefc98ba897d0a5

Also same file in this URL:

https://www.companyName.com/bundles/bee36741ui17054e121c8d72b59a96

var _ac=["\x4d\x6f\x6e\x6f\x73\x70\x61\x63\x65","\x55\x6e\x69\x74\x79\x20\x50\x6c\x61\x79\x65\x72","\x73\x66\x34","\x43\x68\x72\x6f\x6d\x65\x20\x52\x65\x6d\x6f\x74\x65\x20\x44\x65\x73\x6b\x74\x6f\x70\x20\x56\x69\x65\x77\x65\x72","\x73\x6c\x69\x63\x65","\x6d\x61\x67\x6e\x65\x74\x6f\x6d\x65\x74\x65\x72","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x77","\x74\x6f\x46\x69\x78\x65\x64","\x66\x70\x63\x66","\x65\x76\x65\x6e\x74","\x22\x7d","\x52\x54\x43\x50\x65\x65\x72\x43\x6f\x6e\x6e\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e","\x4d\x69\x63\x72\x6f\x73\x6f\x66\x74\x20\x54\x61\x69\x20\x4c\x65","\x67\x65\x74\x43\x6f\x6e\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x63\x74\x61","\x23\x66\x36\x30","\x5c\x27","\x61\x62\x63\x64\x65\x66\x68\x69\x6a\x6b\x6c\x6d\x6e\x6f\x70\x71\x72\x73\x74\x75\x76\x78\x79\x7a\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38\x39\x30\x3b\x2b\x2d\x2e","\x2d\x31","\x61\x70\x70\x56\x65\x72\x73\x69\x6f\x6e","\x63\x61\x6c\x63\x5f\x66\x70","\x69\x6e\x70\x75\x74","\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67","\x5f\x73\x65\x74\x50\x6f\x77\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x70\x6f\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x64\x6f\x77\x6e","\x58\x4d\x4c\x48\x74\x74\x70\x52\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74","\x70\x65\x72\x6d\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6f\x6e\x73","\x76\x63","\x78","\x6a\x73\x5f\x70\x6f\x73\x74","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x63\x74","\x74\x6f\x75\x63\x68\x73\x74\x61\x72\x74","\x6f\x6e\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x63\x68\x61\x6e\x67\x65","\x68\x6f\x73\x74\x6e\x61\x6d\x65","\x7d","\x70\x65\x5f\x63\x6e\x74","\x68\x6b\x70","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x6d\x63\x5f\x69\x6e\x64\x78","\x73\x74\x61\x63\x6b","\x75\x70\x64\x61\x74\x65\x74","\x6c\x61\x6e\x67","\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65","\x6d\x6f\x7a\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x69\x6c\x69\x74\x79\x63\x68\x61\x6e\x67\x65","\x64\x6d\x5f\x64\x69\x73","\x69\x73\x54\x72\x75\x73\x74\x65\x64","\x74\x65\x78\x74","\x6d\x6f\x7a\x49\x6e\x6e\x65\x72\x53\x63\x72\x65\x65\x6e\x59","\x4f\x70\x65\x6e\x20\x53\x61\x6e\x73","\x63\x61\x74\x63\x68","\x3a","\x73\x73\x68","\x6f\x6e\x70\x6f\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x64\x6f\x77\x6e","\x69\x6e\x6e\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4d\x4c","\x76\x63\x5f\x63\x6e\x74\x5f\x6c\x6d\x74","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x78\x74\x65\x6e\x73\x69\x6f\x6e","\x72\x65\x71\x75\x69\x72\x65\x64","\x4d\x61\x63\x20\x4f\x53\x20\x58\x20\x31\x30\x5f\x35","\x61\x74\x74\x61\x63\x68\x45\x76\x65\x6e\x74","\x61\x6a\x5f\x69\x6e\x64\x78","\x73\x70\x61\x77\x6e","\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6c\x74\x5f\x73\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6f\x6e","\x70\x73\x75\x62","\x67\x79\x72\x6f\x73\x63\x6f\x70\x65","\x63\x61\x6c\x6c","\x73\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6f\x6e\x53\x74\x6f\x72\x61\x67\x65","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x6c\x67","\x30","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x70\x73\x6e","\x47\x45\x54","\x69\x73\x49\x67\x6e","\x69\x50\x68\x6f\x6e\x65","\x63\x66\x5f\x75\x72\x6c","\x64\x6f\x65\x5f\x63\x6e\x74","\x64\x69\x73\x70\x6c\x61\x79","\x62\x6f\x64\x79","\x62\x65\x74\x61","\x70\x6f\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x72\x54\x79\x70\x65","\x53\x68\x72\x65\x65\x20\x44\x65\x76\x61\x6e\x61\x67\x61\x72\x69\x20\x37\x31\x34","\x70\x6c\x65\x6e","\x73\x65\x6e\x64\x42\x65\x61\x63\x6f\x6e","\x48\x54\x4d\x4c\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74","\x69\x6e\x64\x65\x78\x65\x64\x44\x62\x4b\x65\x79","\x65\x6e\x41\x64\x64\x48\x69\x64\x64\x65\x6e","\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x5f\x74\x69\x6d\x65","\x63\x68\x65\x63\x6b\x5f\x73\x74\x6f\x70\x5f\x70\x72\x6f\x74\x6f\x63\x6f\x6c","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x72","\x73\x74\x6f\x72\x65\x57\x65\x62\x57\x69\x64\x65\x54\x72\x61\x63\x6b\x69\x6e\x67\x45\x78\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e","\x77\x72\x63\x3a","\x24\x63\x64\x63\x5f\x61\x73\x64\x6a\x66\x6c\x61\x73\x75\x74\x6f\x70\x66\x68\x76\x63\x5a\x4c\x6d\x63\x66\x6c\x5f","\x74\x6f","\x68\x6e","\x6f\x70\x63\x3a","\x2c","\x4d\x6f\x6e\x61\x63\x6f","\x75\x6e\x64\x65\x66","\x78\x61\x67\x67","\x63\x6b\x61","\x73\x71\x72\x74","\x6e\x61\x76\x5f\x70\x65\x72\x6d","\x66\x69\x64\x63\x6e\x74","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6c\x65\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4e\x61\x6d\x65","\x32\x64","\x72\x69\x72","\x62\x6d\x69\x73\x63","\x50\x72\x65\x73\x73\x20\x53\x74\x61\x72\x74\x20\x32\x50","\x67\x61\x6d\x6d\x61","\x70\x64\x75\x63\x65\x5f\x63\x6e\x74","\x6b\x65\x5f\x76\x65\x6c","\x64\x6f\x61\x5f\x74\x68\x72\x6f\x74\x74\x6c\x65","\x6d\x65\x5f\x76\x65\x6c","\x3c\x69\x6e\x69\x74\x2f\x3e","\x41\x70\x70\x6c\x65\x20\x4c\x69\x47\x6f\x74\x68\x69\x63","\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x68\x66","\x63\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6e\x74\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x79\x31","\x76\x69\x73\x69\x62\x69\x6c\x69\x74\x79\x63\x68\x61\x6e\x67\x65","\x42\x61\x74\x61\x6e\x67","\x67\x65\x74\x5f\x73\x74\x6f\x70\x5f\x73\x69\x67\x6e\x61\x6c\x73","\x6a\x6f\x69\x6e","\x54\x49\x2d\x4e\x73\x70\x69\x72\x65","\x73\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6f\x6e\x5f\x69\x64","\x43\x61\x6e\x74\x61\x72\x65\x6c\x6c","\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\x6f\x6e","\x6f\x39","\x55\x52\x4c","\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6e\x67\x69\x66\x79","\x68\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x74\x73","\x4c\x61\x74\x6f","\x63\x68\x6b\x6e\x75\x6c\x6c","\x66\x6f\x6e\x74","\x6f\x6e","\x46\x69\x6c\x65\x52\x65\x61\x64\x65\x72","\x62\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x5f\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65","\x72\x6f\x74\x61\x74\x65\x5f\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74","\x70\x61\x72\x73\x65\x49\x6e\x74","\x78\x32","\x72\x65\x71\x75\x65\x73\x74\x4d\x65\x64\x69\x61\x4b\x65\x79\x53\x79\x73\x74\x65\x6d\x41\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73","\x66\x69\x72\x73\x74\x4c\x6f\x61\x64","\x6d\x6f\x6e\x6f\x73\x70\x61\x63\x65","\x39\x30\x70\x78","\x63\x6f\x6f\x6b\x69\x65\x45\x6e\x61\x62\x6c\x65\x64","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x72\x74","\x70\x65\x6e","\x69\x73\x20\x6e\x6f\x74\x20\x61\x20\x76\x61\x6c\x69\x64\x20\x65\x6e\x75\x6d\x20\x76\x61\x6c\x75\x65\x20\x6f\x66\x20\x74\x79\x70\x65\x20\x50\x65\x72\x6d\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6f\x6e\x4e\x61\x6d\x65","\x57\x65\x62\x4b\x69\x74\x2d\x69\x6e\x74\x65\x67\x72\x69\x65\x72\x74\x65\x20\x50\x44\x46","\x6d\x6e\x5f\x70\x6f\x6c\x6c","\x63\x72\x65\x64\x65\x6e\x74\x69\x61\x6c\x73","\x63\x68\x61\x72\x41\x74","\x2d\x31\x2c\x32\x2c\x2d\x39\x34\x2c\x2d\x31\x32\x30\x2c","\x72\x67\x62\x28\x31\x32\x30\x2c\x20\x31\x38\x36\x2c\x20\x31\x37\x36\x29","\x72\x61\x6e\x64\x6f\x6d","\x61\x75\x74\x68"];var _cf=_cf||[],bmak=bmak&&bmak_ac[378]&&bmak_ac[378]?bmak:{ver:1.68,ke_cnt_lmt:150,mme_cnt_lmt:100,mduce_cnt_lmt:75,pme_cnt_lmt:25,pduce_cnt_lmt:25,tme_cnt_lmt:25,tduce_cnt_lmt:25,doe_cnt_lmt:10,dme_cnt_lmt:10,vc_cnt_lmt:100,doa_throttle:0,dma_throttle:0,session_id:_ac[678],js_post:!1,loc:_ac[328],cf_url:_ac[45]===document[_ac[225]][_ac[200]]?_ac[478]:_ac[424],params_url:(_ac[45]===document[_ac[225]][_ac[200]]?_ac[478]:_ac[424])+document[_ac[225]][_ac[651]]+_ac[85],auth:_ac[328],api_public_key:_ac[41],aj_lmt_doact:1,aj_lmt_dmact:1,aj_lmt_tact:1,ce_js_post:0,init_time:0,informinfo:_ac[328],prevfid:-1,fidcnt:0,sensor_data:0,ins:null,cns:null,enGetLoc:0,enReadDocUrl:1,disFpCalOnTimeout:0,xagg:-1,pen:-1,brow:_ac[328],browver:_ac[328],psub:_ac[206],lang:_ac[206],prod:_ac[206],plen:-1,doadma_en:0,sdfn:[],d2:0,d3:0,thr:0,cs:_ac[512],hn:_ac[51],z1:0,o9:0,vc:_ac[328],y1:2016,ta:0,tst:-1,t_tst:0,ckie:_ac[212],n_ck:_ac[684],ckurl:0,bm:!1,mr:_ac[636],altFonts:!1,rst:!1,runFonts:!1,fsp:!1,firstLoad:!0,pstate:!1,mn_mc_lmt:10,mn_state:0,mn_mc_indx:0,mn_sen:0,mn_tout:100,mn_stout:1e3,mn_ct:1,mn_cc:_ac[328],mn_cd:1e4,mn_lc:[],mn_ld:[],mn_lcl:0,mn_al:[],mn_il:[],mn_tcl:[],mn_r:[],mn_rt:0,mn_wt:0,mn_abck:_ac[328],mn_psn:_ac[328],mn_ts:_ac[328],mn_lg:[],loap:1,dcs:0,ir:function(){bmak[_ac[497]]=Date[_ac[496]]?Date_ac[496]:+new Date,bmak[_ac[426]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[2]]=0,bmak[_ac[725]]=0,bmak[_ac[243]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[21]]=0,bmak[_ac[9]]=0,bmak[_ac[727]]=0,bmak[_ac[287]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[205]]=0,bmak[_ac[724]]=0,bmak[_ac[28]]=0,bmak[_ac[321]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[509]]=0,bmak[_ac[114]]=0,bmak[_ac[353]]=0,bmak[_ac[4]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[690]]=0,bmak[_ac[518]]=0,bmak[_ac[164]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[117]]=0,bmak[_ac[59]]=0,bmak[_ac[341]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[616]]=0,bmak[_ac[676]]=0,bmak[_ac[76]]=0,bmak[_ac[289]]=-1,bmak[_ac[327]]=0,bmak[_ac[449]]=0,bmak[_ac[384]]=0,bmak[_ac[116]]=0,bmak[_ac[653]]=0,bmak[_ac[436]]=0,bmak[_ac[716]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[516]]=0,bmak[_ac[52]]=!1,bmak[_ac[393]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[391]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[668]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[429]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[413]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[593]]=_ac[328],bmak[_ac[557]]=0},get_cf_date:function(){return Date[_ac[496]]?Date_ac[496]:+new Date},sd_debug:function(t){if(!bmak[_ac[647]]){var a=t;_ac[640]==typeof _sd_trace?_sd_trace+=a:_sd_trace=a}},pi:function(t){return parseInt(t)},uar:function(){return window[_ac[465]][_ac[234]][_ac[595]](/%7C%22/g,_ac%5B328%5D)},gd:function(){var t=bmak_ac[99],a=_ac[328]+bmak_ac[90],e=bmak[_ac[497]]/2,n=-1,o=-1,m=-1,r=-1,i=-1,c=-1,b=-1;try{n=window[_ac[115]]?window[_ac[115]][_ac[282]]:-1}catch(t){n=-1}try{o=window[_ac[115]]?window[_ac[115]][_ac[407]]:-1}catch(t){o=-1}try{m=window[_ac[115]]?window[_ac[115]][_ac[561]]:-1}catch(t){m=-1}try{r=window[_ac[115]]?window[_ac[115]][_ac[745]]:-1}catch(t){r=-1}try{i=window[_ac[559]]||(document[_ac[692]]&&_ac[48]in document[_ac[692]]?document[_ac[692]][_ac[48]]:document[_ac[278]]&&_ac[48]in document[_ac[278]]?document[_ac[278]][_ac[48]]:-1)}catch(t){i=-1}try{c=window[_ac[597]]||(document[_ac[692]]&&_ac[369]in document[_ac[692]]?document[_ac[692]][_ac[369]]:document[_ac[278]]&&_ac[369]in document[_ac[278]]?document[_ac[278]][_ac[369]]:-1)}catch(t){c=-1}try{b=_ac[547]in window&&void 0!==window[_ac[547]]?window[_ac[547]]:-1}catch(t){b=-1}bmak[_ac[573]]=bmak_ac[161];var d=Math_ac[771],s=bmak_ac[161],k=d+_ac[328];return k=k_ac[622]+s,bmak_ac[253],bmak_ac[340],bmak_ac[80],bmak_ac[721],t+_ac[266]+bmak[_ac[713]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[679]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[658]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[81]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[696]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[763]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[88]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[460]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[573]]+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[607]]+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+o+_ac[710]+m+_ac[710]+r+_ac[710]+c+_ac[710]+i+_ac[710]+b+_ac[710]+bmak_ac[752]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+k+_ac[710]+e+_ac[710]+bmak[_ac[516]]+_ac[218]+bmak[_ac[159]]},get_browser:function(){navigator[_ac[172]]&&(bmak[_ac[679]]=navigator[_ac[172]]),navigator[_ac[290]]&&(bmak[_ac[658]]=navigator[_ac[290]]),navigator[_ac[176]]&&(bmak[_ac[81]]=navigator[_ac[176]]),bmak[_ac[696]]=void 0!==navigator[_ac[335]]?navigator[_ac[335]][_ac[450]]:-1},gbrv:function(){navigator[_ac[179]]&&navigator[_ac[179]]_ac[383]_ac[469]_ac[666]},bc:function(){var t=window[_ac[299]]?1:0,a=window[_ac[643]]?1:0,e=window[_ac[558]]?1:0,n=window[_ac[129]]?1:0,o=window[_ac[190]]?1:0,m=window[_ac[162]]?1:0,r=window[_ac[142]]?1:0,i=window[_ac[677]]?1:0,c=window[_ac[554]]?1:0,b=Function[_ac[455]][_ac[20]]?1:0,d=window[_ac[414]]?1:0,s=window[_ac[463]]?1:0;try{var k=window[_ac[597]]?1:0}catch(t){var k=0}try{var l=window[_ac[547]]?1:0}catch(t){var l=0}bmak[_ac[713]]=t+(a<<1)+(e<<2)+(n<<3)+(o<<4)+(m<<5)+(r<<6)+(i<<7)+(k<<8)+(l<<9)+(c<<10)+(b<<11)+(d<<12)+(s<<13)},bmisc:function(){bmak[_ac[763]]=window[_ac[236]]?1:0,bmak[_ac[88]]=window[_ac[54]]?1:0,bmak[_ac[460]]=window[_ac[123]]?1:0},bd:function(){var t=[],a=window[_ac[542]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var e=0;window[_ac[402]]&&_ac[402]in window&&(e=1),t_ac[545];var n=_ac[514]==typeof document[_ac[548]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var o=window[_ac[554]]&&window[_ac[554]][_ac[568]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var m=navigator[_ac[380]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var r=window[_ac[606]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var i=_ac[193]!=typeof InstallTrigger?1:0;t_ac[545];var c=window[_ac[698]]&&Object[_ac[455]][_ac[242]]_ac[681]_ac[26]>0?1:0;t_ac[545];var b=_ac[741]==typeof window[_ac[629]]||_ac[741]==typeof window[_ac[173]]||_ac[741]==typeof window[_ac[362]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var d=_ac[664]in window?window[_ac[664]]:0;t_ac[545],bmak[_ac[55]]=bmak_ac[161];var s=_ac[741]==typeof navigator[_ac[396]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var k=_ac[741]==typeof navigator[_ac[601]]?1:0;t_ac[545];var l=Array[_ac[455]][_ac[501]]?0:1;t_ac[545];var u=_ac[751]in window?1:0;return t_ac[545],t_ac[737]},fas:function(){try{return Boolean(navigator[_ac[767]])+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[560]])<<1)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[388]])<<2)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[204]])<<3)+(Boolean(Math[_ac[332]])<<4)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[400]])<<5)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[480]])<<6)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[281]])<<7)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[603]])<<8)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[47]])<<9)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[219]])<<10)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[472]])<<11)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[300]])<<12)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[563]])<<13)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[644]])<<14)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[538]])<<15)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[757]])<<16)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[482]])<<17)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[697]])<<18)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[397]])<<19)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[704]])<<20)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[25]])<<21)+(Boolean(navigator[_ac[392]])<<22)+(Boolean(Number[_ac[755]])<<23)+(Boolean(Math[_ac[40]])<<24)}catch(t){return 0}},getmr:function(){try{if(_ac[193]==typeof performance||void 0===performance[_ac[496]]||_ac[193]==typeof JSON)return void(bmak[_ac[338]]=_ac[712]);for(var t=_ac[328],a=1e3,e=[Math[_ac[271]],Math[_ac[127]],Math[_ac[310]],Math[_ac[584]],Math[_ac[227]],Math[_ac[385]],Math[_ac[771]],Math[_ac[552]],Math[_ac[715]],isFinite,isNaN,parseFloat,parseInt,JSON[_ac[614]]],n=0;n<e[_ac[450]];n++){var o=[],m=0,r=performance_ac[496],i=0,c=0;if(void 0!==e[n]){for(i=0;i<a&&m<.6;i++){for(var b=performance_ac[496],d=0;d<4e3;d++)en;var s=performance_ac[496];o_ac[545],m=s-r}var k=o_ac[27];c=k[Math_ac[257]]/5}t=t+c+_ac[710]}bmak[_ac[338]]=t}catch(t){bmak[_ac[338]]=_ac[555]}},sed:function(){var t;t=window[_ac[706]]||document[_ac[706]]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var a;a=null!=window[_ac[520]][_ac[278]]_ac[585]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var e;e=void 0!==navigator[_ac[54]]&&navigator[_ac[54]]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var n;n=void 0!==window[_ac[54]]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var o;o=void 0!==window[_ac[56]]||void 0!==document[_ac[56]]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var m;m=null!=window[_ac[520]][_ac[278]]_ac[585]?_ac[160]:_ac[684];var r;return r=null!=window[_ac[520]][_ac[278]]_ac[585]?_ac[160]:_ac[684],[t,a,e,n,o,m,r]_ac[737]},cma:function(t,a){try{if(1==a&&bmak[_ac[21]]<bmak[_ac[39]]||1!=a&&bmak[_ac[9]]<bmak[_ac[211]]){var e=t||window[_ac[627]],n=-1,o=-1;e&&e[_ac[106]]&&e[_ac[447]]?(n=Math_ac[257],o=Math_ac[257]):e&&e[_ac[556]]&&e[_ac[259]]&&(n=Math_ac[257],o=Math_ac[257]);var m=e[_ac[342]];null==m&&(m=e[_ac[135]]);var r=bmak_ac[256],i=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],c=bmak[_ac[116]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+i+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+o;if(1!=a){c=c+_ac[710]+r;var b=void 0!==e[_ac[354]]?e[_ac[354]]:e[_ac[522]];null!=b&&1!=b&&(c=c+_ac[710]+b)}void 0!==e[_ac[662]]&&!1===e[_ac[662]]&&(c+=_ac[411]),c+=_ac[511],bmak[_ac[727]]=bmak[_ac[727]]+bmak[_ac[116]]+a+i+n+o,bmak[_ac[243]]=bmak[_ac[243]]+c,bmak[_ac[82]]+=i}1==a?bmak[_ac[21]]++:bmak[_ac[9]]++,bmak[_ac[116]]++,bmak[_ac[647]]&&3==a&&(bmak[_ac[289]]=1,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak[_ac[524]]=1)}catch(t){}},x2:function(){var t=bmak[_ac[600]],a=t(98)+t(109)+t(97)+t(107),e=t(103)+t(101)+t(116)+t(95)+t(99)+t(102)+t(95)+t(100)+t(97)+t(116)+t(101),n=window[a][e],o=0;return _ac[741]==typeof n&&(o=n()),o},np:function(){var t=[],a=[_ac[134],_ac[314],_ac[545],_ac[5],_ac[475],_ac[128],_ac[8],_ac[275],_ac[297],_ac[388],_ac[244],_ac[254],_ac[31],_ac[680],_ac[623],_ac[445],_ac[302],_ac[412],_ac[84],_ac[32]];try{if(!navigator[_ac[644]])return void(bmak[_ac[716]]=6);bmak[_ac[716]]=8;var e=function(a,e){return navigator[_ac[644]]_ac[17][_ac[469]](function(a){switch(a[_ac[730]]){case _ac[292]:t[e]=1;break;case _ac[120]:t[e]=2;break;case _ac[489]:t[e]=0;break;default:t[e]=5}})_ac[666]},n=a[_ac[320]](function(t,a){return e(t,a)});Promise_ac[417]_ac[469]}catch(t){bmak[_ac[716]]=7}},cpa:function(t,a){try{var e=!1;if(1==a&&bmak[_ac[205]]<bmak[_ac[140]]||1!=a&&bmak[_ac[724]]<bmak[_ac[565]]){var n=t||window[_ac[627]];if(n&&_ac[549]!=n[_ac[694]]){e=!0;var o=-1,m=-1;n&&n[_ac[106]]&&n[_ac[447]]?(o=Math_ac[257],m=Math_ac[257]):n&&n[_ac[556]]&&n[_ac[259]]&&(o=Math_ac[257],m=Math_ac[257]);var r=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],i=bmak[_ac[653]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+r+_ac[710]+o+_ac[710]+m;void 0!==n[_ac[662]]&&!1===n[_ac[662]]&&(i+=_ac[602]),bmak[_ac[28]]=bmak[_ac[28]]+bmak[_ac[653]]+a+r+o+m,bmak[_ac[287]]=bmak[_ac[287]]+i+_ac[511],bmak[_ac[82]]+=r,1==a?bmak[_ac[205]]++:bmak[_ac[724]]++}}1==a?bmak[_ac[205]]++:bmak[_ac[724]]++,bmak[_ac[653]]++,bmak[_ac[647]]&&3==a&&e&&(bmak[_ac[289]]=2,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak[_ac[524]]=1)}catch(t){}},ab:function(t){if(null==t)return-1;try{for(var a=0,e=0;e<t[_ac[450]];e++){var n=t_ac[213];n<128&&(a+=n)}return a}catch(t){return-2}},ff:function(t){return String_ac[507]},cal_dis:function(t){var a=t[0]-t[1],e=t[2]-t[3],n=t[4]-t[5],o=Math_ac[715];return Math_ac[257]},to:function(){var t=bmak_ac[756]%1e7;bmak[_ac[607]]=t;for(var a=t,e=bmak_ac[161],n=0;n<5;n++){var o=bmak_ac[161]%10,m=o+1;op=bmak_ac[44],a=op(a,m)}bmak[_ac[742]]=a*e},jrs:function(t){for(var a=Math_ac[257],e=String(t*a),n=0,o=[],m=e[_ac[450]]>=18;o[_ac[450]]<6;)o_ac[545],n=m?n+3:n+2;return[a,bmak_ac[30]]},fm:function(){var t=[_ac[618],_ac[331],_ac[112],_ac[526],_ac[570],_ac[525],_ac[261],_ac[71],_ac[695],_ac[630],_ac[523],_ac[73],_ac[722],_ac[245]],a=document_ac[615];a[_ac[670]]=_ac[416],a[_ac[419]][_ac[274]]=_ac[214];var e=_ac[328],n=document_ac[718][0];if(n){for(var o in t)a[_ac[419]][_ac[423]]=t[o],n_ac[210],e+=t[o]+_ac[667]+a[_ac[207]]+_ac[710]+a[_ac[468]]+_ac[511],n_ac[273];bmak[_ac[393]]=bmak_ac[130]}else bmak[_ac[393]]=_ac[328];bmak[_ac[391]]=_ac[168]in window&&void 0!==window[_ac[168]]?window[_ac[168]]:-1},wgl:function(){try{var t=document_ac[615],a=t_ac[631];bmak[_ac[429]]=_ac[267],bmak[_ac[413]]=_ac[267],bmak[_ac[593]]=_ac[267],bmak[_ac[557]]=0,a&&(bmak[_ac[429]]=_ac[451],bmak[_ac[413]]=_ac[451],bmak[_ac[593]]=_ac[451],a_ac[418]&&(bmak[_ac[593]]=bmak_ac[130],bmak[_ac[557]]=a_ac[418][_ac[450]],a_ac[418]_ac[26]>=0&&(bmak[_ac[429]]=a_ac[148],bmak[_ac[413]]=a_ac[148])))}catch(t){bmak[_ac[429]]=_ac[15],bmak[_ac[413]]=_ac[15],bmak[_ac[593]]=_ac[15],bmak[_ac[557]]=0}},csh:function(){if(window[_ac[154]]){var t=window[_ac[154]]_ac[98];if(t[_ac[450]]>0){for(var a=_ac[328],e=0;e<t[_ac[450]];e++)a+=t[e][_ac[546]]+_ac[613]+t[e][_ac[658]];bmak[_ac[668]]=bmak_ac[130]}else bmak[_ac[668]]=_ac[684]}else bmak[_ac[668]]=_ac[267]},gf:function(t){var a;if(a=null==t?document[_ac[183]]:t,null==document[_ac[183]])return-1;var e=a_ac[585];if(null==e){var n=a_ac[585];return null==n?-1:bmak_ac[90]}return bmak_ac[90]},cc:function(t){var a=t%4;2==a&&(a=3);var e=42+a,n=function(t,a){return 0};if(42==e)var n=function(t,a){return t*a};else if(43==e)var n=function(t,a){return t+a};else var n=function(t,a){return t-a};return n},isIgn:function(t){var a=document[_ac[183]];if(null==document[_ac[183]])return 0;var e=a_ac[585];return 1==(null==e?-1:bmak_ac[235])&&bmak[_ac[717]]>12&&-2==t?1:0},cka:function(t,a){try{var e=t||window[_ac[627]],n=-1,o=1;if(bmak[_ac[2]]<bmak[_ac[326]]&&e){n=e[_ac[74]];var m=e[_ac[317]],r=e[_ac[309]]?1:0,i=e[_ac[437]]?1:0,c=e[_ac[103]]?1:0,b=e[_ac[18]]?1:0,d=8*r+4*i+2*c+b,s=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],k=bmak_ac[256],l=0;m&&n&&(n=0!=m&&0!=n&&m!=n?-1:0!=n?n:m),0==i&&0==c&&0==b&&n>=32&&(n=3==a&&n>=32&&n<=126?-2:n>=33&&n<=47?-3:n>=112&&n<=123?-4:-2),k!=bmak[_ac[387]]?(bmak[_ac[717]]=0,bmak[_ac[387]]=k):bmak[_ac[717]]=bmak[_ac[717]]+1;if(0==bmak_ac[687]){var u=bmak[_ac[2]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+s+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+l+_ac[710]+d+_ac[710]+k;void 0!==e[_ac[662]]&&!1===e[_ac[662]]&&(u+=_ac[602]),u+=_ac[511],bmak[_ac[426]]=bmak[_ac[426]]+u,bmak[_ac[725]]=bmak[_ac[725]]+bmak[_ac[2]]+a+s+n+d+k,bmak[_ac[82]]+=s}else o=0}o&&e&&bmak[_ac[2]]++,!bmak[_ac[647]]||1!=a||13!=n&&9!=n||(bmak[_ac[289]]=3,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak[_ac[524]]=1)}catch(t){}},cta:function(t,a){try{if(1==a&&bmak[_ac[509]]<bmak[_ac[169]]||1!=a&&bmak[_ac[114]]<bmak[_ac[466]]){var e=t||window[_ac[627]],n=-1,o=-1;e&&e[_ac[106]]&&e[_ac[447]]?(n=Math_ac[257],o=Math_ac[257]):e&&e[_ac[556]]&&e[_ac[259]]&&(n=Math_ac[257],o=Math_ac[257]);var m=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],r=bmak[_ac[436]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+m+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+o;void 0!==e[_ac[662]]&&!1===e[_ac[662]]&&(r+=_ac[602]),bmak[_ac[321]]=bmak[_ac[321]]+r+_ac[511],bmak[_ac[82]]+=m,bmak[_ac[353]]=bmak[_ac[353]]+bmak[_ac[436]]+a+m+n+o,bmak[_ac[726]]=0,bmak[_ac[379]]=0}1==a?bmak[_ac[509]]++:bmak[_ac[114]]++,bmak[_ac[436]]++,bmak[_ac[647]]&&2==a&&bmak[_ac[384]]<bmak[_ac[375]]&&(bmak[_ac[289]]=5,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak[_ac[524]]=1,bmak[_ac[384]]++)}catch(t){}},getFloatVal:function(t){try{if(-1!=bmak_ac[748]&&!isNaN(t)){var a=parseFloat(t);if(!isNaN(a))return a_ac[625]}}catch(t){}return-1},cdoa:function(t){try{if(bmak[_ac[690]]<bmak[_ac[459]]&&bmak[_ac[726]]<2&&t){var a=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],e=bmak_ac[325],n=bmak_ac[325],o=bmak_ac[325],m=bmak[_ac[690]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+e+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+o;void 0!==t[_ac[662]]&&!1===t[_ac[662]]&&(m+=_ac[602]),bmak[_ac[4]]=bmak[_ac[4]]+m+_ac[511],bmak[_ac[82]]+=a,bmak[_ac[518]]=bmak[_ac[518]]+bmak[_ac[690]]+a,bmak[_ac[690]]++}bmak[_ac[647]]&&bmak[_ac[690]]>1&&bmak[_ac[327]]<bmak[_ac[108]]&&(bmak[_ac[289]]=6,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak[_ac[524]]=1,bmak[_ac[327]]++),bmak[_ac[726]]++}catch(t){}},cdma:function(t){try{if(bmak[_ac[117]]<bmak[_ac[222]]&&bmak[_ac[379]]<2&&t){var a=bmak_ac[485]-bmak[_ac[497]],e=-1,n=-1,o=-1;t[_ac[264]]&&(e=bmak_ac[325],n=bmak_ac[325],o=bmak_ac[325]);var m=-1,r=-1,i=-1;t[_ac[425]]&&(m=bmak_ac[325],r=bmak_ac[325],i=bmak_ac[325]);var c=-1,b=-1,d=1;t[_ac[298]]&&(c=bmak_ac[325],b=bmak_ac[325],d=bmak_ac[325]);var s=bmak[_ac[117]]+_ac[710]+a+_ac[710]+e+_ac[710]+n+_ac[710]+o+_ac[710]+m+_ac[710]+r+_ac[710]+i+_ac[710]+c+_ac[710]+b+_ac[710]+d;void 0!==t[_ac[662]]&&!1===t[_ac[662]]&&(s+=_ac[602]),bmak[_ac[164]]=bmak[_ac[164]]+s+_ac[511],bmak[_ac[82]]+=a,bmak[_ac[59]]=bmak[_ac[59]]+bmak[_ac[117]]+a,bmak[_ac[117]]++}bmak[_ac[647]]&&bmak[_ac[117]]>1&&bmak[_ac[449]]<bmak[_ac[10]]&&(bmak[_ac[289]]=7,bmak_ac[605],bmak_ac[432],bmak9],bmak[_ac[216]],!0),document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299],document_ac[299]):document[_ac[675]]&&(document_ac[675],document[_ac[675]](_ac[649]d}

Not sure what is or where its from.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be something which is generated within AEM as the path `/webcontent` isn't a native path within the product.

However Hex decoding the initial few lines gives the following output

```
var _ac = ["Monospace","Unity Player","sf4","Chrome Remote Desktop Viewer","slice","magnetometer","mn_w","toFixed","fpcf","event",""}","RTCPeerConnection","Microsoft Tai Le","getContext","cta","#f60","\'","abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvxyz1234567890;+-.","-1","appVersion","calc_fp","input","string","_setPowState","pointerdown","XMLHttpRequest","permissions","vc","x","js_post","mn_ct","touchstart","onreadystatechange","hostname","}","pe_cnt","hkp","mn_mc_indx","stack","updatet","lang","value","mozvisibilitychange","dm_dis","isTrusted","text","mozInnerScreenY","Open Sans","catch",":","ssh","onpointerdown","innerHTML","vc_cnt_lmt","getExtension","required","Mac OS X 10_5","attachEvent","aj_indx","spawn","default_session","psub","gyroscope","call","sessionStorage","mn_lg","0","mn_psn","GET","isIgn","iPhone","cf_url","doe_cnt","display","body","beta","pointerType","Shree Devanagari 714","plen","sendBeacon","HTMLElement","indexedDbKey","enAddHidden","init_time","check_stop_protocol","mn_r","storeWebWideTrackingException","wrc:","$cdc_asdjflasutopfhvcZLmcfl_","to","hn","opc:",",","Monaco","undef","xagg","cka","sqrt","nav_perm","fidcnt","getElementsByTagName","2d","rir","bmisc","Press Start 2P","gamma","pduce_cnt","ke_vel","doa_throttle","me_vel","<init/>","Apple LiGothic","state","hf","currentScript","y1","visibilitychange","Batang","get_stop_signals","join","TI-Nspire","session_id","Cantarell","function","o9","URL","stringify","height","mn_ts","Lato","chknull","font","on","FileReader","bd","get_cookie","rotate_right","parseInt","x2","requestMediaKeySystemAccess","firstLoad","monospace","90px","cookieEnabled","mn_rt","pen","is not a valid enum value of type PermissionName","WebKit-integrierte PDF","mn_poll","credentials","charAt","-1,2,-94,-120,","rgb(120, 186, 176)","random","auth"];
```

It appears to be Akamai's Bot Manager SDK or Bot Manager code based on [this article](https://grantwinney.com/websites-requesting-access-to-motion-sensors/) and [this GitHub source code](https://gist.github.com/fronbasal/e11945fea1410085c5db2a62686f0192). However, I cannot confirm the same. In case your setup is making use of Akamai then it may make sense.